# Converting a JavaScript function to jQuery - Select option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

This is literally the first time I've worked with jQuery and I've read the entire chapter in my textbook but am finding a hard time wrapping my head around it. I'm attempting to convert a JavaScript function (a simple option selection drop-down list) to jQuery. I've attempted a few lines of code that I've gotten from the book or from w3schools and api.query but to no avail. I'll try to make this quick and simple, I just cannot understand jQuery for some reason.

What I've attempted usually doesn't work. Before my option list works fine, then I tried experimenting but I didn't get too far.

I also apolgize for the vagueness of the question, I'd appreciate any help!
Here's something I've tried:

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
var c = ???
if ($(c...
```

**calc.js and index.html below it**

```js
function selectedCountry() {
  var c = document.getElementById("countryChooser").value;
  var message;
  if (c == "nothing") { //if they selected the default option, error pops up.
    alert("Please select a country.");
  } else if (c == "usa") {
    message = "United States of America";
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "Your country is: " + message;
  } else if (c == "canada") {
    message = "Canada";
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "Your country is: " + message;
  } else {
    message = "Mexico";
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "Your country is: " + message;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src = "calc.js"></script> <!--JavaSript link -->

<select name="countrylist" id="countryChooser" onchange="selectedCountry()">
 <option value="nothing">Select a country</option>
 <option value="usa">United States of America</option>
 <option value="canada">Canada</option>
 <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
</select>
<p id="count"></p>
```

Comment: jQuery is quite easy once you get your head around it, it seems you're struggling with using a [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) right now. What `document.getElementById("countryChooser")` does is finds an element in the HTML with the id _countryChooser_ to replace this with jQuery code you'd need to do `$("#countryChooser")` and the to get the value of that element you can use `.val()` P.S. your code might be better suited to use a `switch` also if this is all your code the variable `message` is pointless, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through `jQuery` you can do it like below:-

***Example:***-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#countryChooser').change(function(){ // on change of select
    if($(this).val()!=='nothing'){ // if selected value is some country
      $('#count').html("Your country is: "+$("#countryChooser option:selected").text()); // get country name and add it to paragraph
    }else{
      $('#count').html("");
      alert('Please select a country.'); // alert for selecting a country
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="countrylist" id="countryChooser">
  <option value="nothing">Select a country</option>
  <option value="usa">United States of America</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
</select>

<p id="count"></p>
```

Comment: Yeah I'll link you to the legitimate site I have uploaded.
http://wheeloftimestory.webege.com/user.html

Comment: @LukeSitler  your site is not opening at my end. trying from past 24 hours

Answer (score 2):

Get an element by id:

```
var c = $('#countryChooser');
```

Get the value of this input/select element

```
var value = c.val();
```

Set the html of an element using the element id

```
$('#count').html('some html');
```

or set the text (html is not parsed this way)

```
$('#count').text('some html');
```

You can also handle the events with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#countryChooser').on('change', function(event) {
       // this is the DOM element with the id 'countryChooser'
       // same as the native: var val = this.value;
       var val = $(this).val();
       // ...
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have bind the `onchange()` event of your select list inside the `jQuery(document).ready()` method. check this out-

// Updated code--

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

$('#countryChooser').on('change' ,function () {
    if(this.selectedIndex){
      $('#count').html("Your country is: "+ this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
   }else{
     $('#count').html("");
    alert("Please select a country.");
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "calc.js"></script> <!--JavaSript link -->

<select name="countrylist" id="countryChooser">
 <option value="nothing">Select a country</option>
 <option value="usa">United States of America</option>
 <option value="canada">Canada</option>
 <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
</select>
<p id="count"></p>
```

Comment: While this does convert some of the code to jQuery, the main bulk is still plain js.

Comment: When using jQuery then why doing this much code. Unnecessary

Comment: @Gerge, miss understood... I just wanted to show that how to call the function from the jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#countryChooser').change(function(){
  var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
  if(selectedCountry == 'nothing'){
    console.log('Select A country');
  }
  else{
    $('#count').html('Your country is '+$('#countryChooser option:selected').text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!--JavaSript link -->

<select name="countrylist" id="countryChooser" >
  <option value="nothing">Select a country</option>
  <option value="usa">United States of America</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
</select>
<p id="count"></p>
```

Please check the code might help you out
thanks